# Reduce Persistent Disk Size

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a **persistent disk of 100GB** attached to a VM instance. But I don't need all that space, and thus don't want to be billed for it. It has some data as well. I took a snapshot of the disk, and tried to create another one.

While trying to create a new one, it wouldn't take a value less that 100GB and says, since the **snapshot is also of 100GB**, the new disk should have a **minimum size of 100GB**.

How can I make a smaller persistent disk from a snapshot? Or reduce the size of the existing one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible TMK. You'll need to create another disk and copy the data over, though you can [expand a snapshot to a larger disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#restoresnapshotlargersize).

Answer (score 6):

I had to recently just do this. I originally created a disk 500GB, but quickly realized that was a mistake as the disk is only using 20GB.

The high-level process involves creating a new instance with the desired smaller disk size. Stopping all services that write to the larger disk *(think MySQL/MongoDB, NGINX/Apache, etc)*. Then, using `rsync` copy over all files from the larger disk to the smaller disk excluding a subset of instance specific data.

Comment: Could you give some `scripts` as a example to understand?

Comment: Try https://donovancraig.com.au/blog/2019/11/22/shrinking-gcp-drives/