# How can the size of the root disk in Google compute engine be decreased?

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381686/how-can-size-of-the-root-disk-in-google-compute-engine-be-increased) address the issue of increasing the size of GCE root disks, but how can they be decreased? I suspect this would require first resizing the root partition to leave unallocated space on the drive, but, even then, it appears that in creating a new disk from a snapshot one is not allowed to specify the disk size to be smaller than its current size. It may be helpful to do this in order to save money on storage once the optimal drive size becomes clearer in the course of a project.

Comment: Another thread suggests that it can't be done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738157/reduce-persistent-disk-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible method is to create a backup of the disk (not snapshot). It would basically involve copying all your files (excluding OS files) from the machine to a google storage bucket.

Now that data is in the bucket, you can create a new instance and easily transfer your data back to your instance without any loss in speed or major cost in network transfers.

Though I would always prefer to have a bit of extra space available.